# How to handle the URL protocol bundle://

Tags: url, osgi, knopflerfish

I try to get a file in my bundle with:

```
File file = new File(bundleContext.getBundle().
getResource("image/logo.jpg").toURI());
```

The result is a IllegalArgumentException with the cause "URI scheme is not "file".

This is logical, but how should i open a file with this URL (bundle://28/image/logo.jpg)?

If i use the regular ClassLoader i get the same result.

**EDIT:**

My Solution:

```
URL url = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("image/logo.jpg");
InputStream in = new BufferedInputstream(url.openStream());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot open a file since there might not be a file ... So just get the input stream instead. That works for all URLs/URIs.